# Размер дочернего экрана в SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Возникла задача, в которой размер View на родительском экране будет зависеть от дочерних View. Как правильно передать размер в свойство viewSize?

```
struct ParentView: View {

    @State var viewSize: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        Text("ChildView") // тут будет View, размер которого надо узнать
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать такую обертку

```
struct ViewSizeReader<Content: View>: View {

    @Binding var size: CGSize

    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content()
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: proxy.size)
                    }
                )
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
            self.size = preferences
        }
    }
}

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGSize
    static var defaultValue: Value = .zero

    static func reduce(value _: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        _ = nextValue()
    }
}
```

Как использовать в коде:

```
struct ParentView: View {

    @State var viewSize: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        ViewSizeReader(size: $viewSize) {
             Text("Тут будет View, размер которого надо узнать")
        }

    }
}
```

Подсмотрел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60861575/3757640)